# Create compile script for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, makefile

I have downloaded an Eclipse project and I want to be able to have other people compile it without using Eclipse. It is a fairly large Java project that is still being worked on. How would I make a compile script that compiles like eclipse?

Comment: Have you considered [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)?

Comment: Are you using a version control system (Git, SVN, ...) if not you should be.

Comment: Yes, Git is being used here. I am planning on making the build script and then submitting a pull request to the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you look into Maven. Basically you'll define a Maven pom file in the root of your Eclipse project directory which will contain your dependencies (jars) as well as compile and assembly configuration. With this in place you can simply checkout a project and run a maven build command against the local directory you checked out to and an executable/deployable package will be created.